# ASP.NET Web API Google OAuth keep return "Access Denied"

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I need to integrate my ASP.NET Web API with Google and Facebook OAuth. I was following all the steps from https://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/
but no luck..

Every time I login to my Google Account, it always returns an "Access denied" xml page.

[image: Every time I login to my Google Account, it always returns an "Access denied" xml page.]
I believe there is something wrong with my code, not my Google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs since I downloaded Taiseer's sample code and run it on my localhost and it succeed to authenticate my Google account.

But no idea why in my code it doesn't work. Desperately need some advice.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Hi DalmTo , I solved this problem a few hours after I post it. I just need to update my Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google library to newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
The issue coming from Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google library. I was using version 3.0.1 but after I update to the newest version, boom... Voila! It works..

Comment: You should post the before code in your question and then the after code in your answer.  This will help others in the future who may have the same issue as you.  This will increase greatly your chances of getting additional points.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error "access_denied" also, because I hadnt added my google email to the list of Test Users in the google developer console, under OAuth consent screen.